# SQL sub select resolution

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables namely customer and product below is there definition

customer

- `customer_id`.
- `customer_name`.

product

- `product_id`.
- `product_name`.

customer table is populated as below

```
customer_id |customer_name
----------------------------
1          |  abc
----------------------------
2          |  efg
------------------------------
```

product table is populated as below

```
product_id|product_name
------------------------------
1          |  chair
-----------------------------
2          |  desk
------------------------------
```

When I run the following query

```
SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM product)
```

my expectation was that it would complain with error no column customer_id in product table, instead this query returns all the rows of customer table. Can anybody explain what is happening here? Why is sub select using the table from parent query and returning results from it without complaining?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `customer_id` in the sub query is unqualified column and doesn't use any alias reference. Then MySQL in this case searches the tables references for this column, therefore, it is resolved as the `customer_id` column from `customer` table.

Aliases should be used in these cases, like this:

```
SELECT c.customer_id 
FROM customer AS c 
WHERE c.customer_id IN (SELECT p.customer_id FROM product as p)
```

In this case you will get the error you are looking for :D

Comment: Does it mean that a query like `DELETE FROM customer WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM product )` will delete all records from customer table? that sounds scary